# Suppose $f$ is an integral defined on $[0,b]$, and

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f$ is integral enough on $[0,b],$ and $g(x)=\int_x^b\frac{f(t)}{t} \, dt$  for $0<x\leq b.$

Prove that $g$ is integrable on $[0,b]$ and $\int_0^b g(x) \, dx=\int_0^b f(t) \, dt$

I know we are trying to prove $\limsup_{n\to 0}\int_n^b g < \infty$, but I tried to look at convergence theorems and I’m at lost, any help or hint? Thanks.

Comment: You need to fix the first line.  It ends with for o.  This is meaningless.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me! Fixed.

Comment: Good revisions! I see you’re really getting the swing of things here $\ddot\smile$ Do you think you could improve your title? Maybe make it more general and reflective of the topic and less of a sentence fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change order of integration.   Write $g(x)=\int_0^b\int_x^b\frac{f(t)}{t}dtdx=\int_0^b\frac{f(t)}{t}\int_0^tdxdt=\int_0^bf(t)dt$

Comment: Got it, so you used Fubini? Thank you very much!